# When the zoom increses (Ctrl + =) , the Markdown preview width shrinks

Tags: visual-studio-code

I like to preview the markdown files with bigger fonts. When I zoom (Ctrl + =), the width of the preview area decreases I have unused (wasted) real estate at the right of the preview area.

I think this is a bug. Is there any workaround?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User/Workspace Settings a property for that.

```
"markdown.preview.fontSize": 100
```

Here is how to set it.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to show all commands.
2. Type `open settings`
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to Open User Settings.
4. Add the `"markdown.preview.fontsize": 100` to the `settings.json`.

Now we have a markdown preview with font size 100.

[image]

Comment: You said that, "When I zoom (Ctrl + =), the width of the preview area decreases..." In the answer, when we increase the font size, the width of the preview area stays the same. So, I feel confused about how the issue persists. You wanted to "preview the markdown files with bigger fonts." This answer provides that. @AllanXu